# Add-ClusterResource Generic Service Policy

Tags: windows, powershell, cluster-computing, powershell-2.0

Im creating a windows generic service through power shell and my command is below

Add-ClusterResource -Name "FileImport" -Group "SQLINST1" -ResourceType "Generic Service"  | Set-ClusterParameter -Name ServiceName -Value "FileImport"

Start-ClusterResource "FileImport" 
This works but i also want to set the policies option . So i want to have the checkbox "if restart is unsuccessful, fail over all resources in this service or application". Is this possible through powershell and can someone help with the missing syntax please.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this in powershell. Please see code below which worked

Get-ClusterResource "FileImport"| % { $_.RestartAction="1"}

Comment: `(Get-ClusterResource "FileImport").RestartAction = 1` is a little simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, you will not find an easy way for that. I use the deprecated old cluster.exe to perform things like that:

```
cluster.exe /cluster:cluster000 res Resname /prop
cluster.exe /cluster:cluster000 res Resname /priv
```

Here you can easily set all the parameters you want.